# SQL UPDATE statement with large HTML data

Tags: sql, replace, escaping

I have some automated workflow, which includes updating a column via SQL with HTML tags in it.

The basic SQL statement goes like this:

```
UPDATE content SET bodytext = '<div class="one two three">Here comes a whole lot of HTML with all special chars and double quotes " and single quotes ' and empty lines and all possible kind of stuff...</div>' WHERE pid = 10;
```

Is there a way to make MariaDB or MySQL to escape things automatically in SQL (without PHP)?

Comment: Write a function that returns the escaped text.

Comment: @nicomp thank you for the idea. Could you, please, elaborate on a minimal example?

Comment: Something like SELECT REPLACE ('a"bc', '"', '\'"\'')

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your input, but I think, I found a solution which works for me. It seems that you actually can tell the SQL server to accept a raw string by this kind of syntax:

`SELECT q'[The 'end' of the day]'`

(Source: https://www.databasestar.com/sql-escape-single-quote/)

So I did the following:

```
SELECT @html := '[<div class="one two three">Here comes a whole lot of HTML with all special chars and double quotes " and single quotes '' and empty lines and all possible kind of stuff...</div>]';
UPDATE content SET bodytext = @html WHERE pid = 10;
```

And it works that way without any escaping problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use prepared statements. This way you separate the statement from it's parameters and don't need to care about additional escaping necessary in plain SQL.

Using functionality provided in PHP's MySQLi driver would simplify the process:

https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Prepared statements are also possible in plain SQL, but I'm not sure if doing it manually would be worth the hassle

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-prepared-statements.html